# Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $Y = \left \{ x \in \mathbb{R}\mid x ≥ 1 \right \}$. Define $G : X → Y$ by $G(x) = e^{x^2}$. Prove that $G$ is onto.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $Y = \left \{ x \in \mathbb{R}\mid x ≥ 1 \right \}$. Define $G : X → Y$ by
$G(x) = e^{x^2}$.
Prove that $G$ is onto.